# How to fix bug with <ul> and <li> in my grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make my portfolio and its pretty good but I have bug in the grid.

[image: grid bug]

Here is the source code:

https://pastecode.io/s/7t652k2n

Here is the website:

http://ludwik-zimmenhof-portfolio.5v.pl

Comment: Div with `Advanced AI` is outside `<div class="w3-content w3-justify w3-text-grey w3-padding-64" id="about">`. It should be inside.

Comment: i dont realy see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements are not nested in a row div

```
<div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px">
    <div class="w3-half w3-margin-bottom">
        <ul class="w3-ul w3-white w3-center w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off">
            <li class="w3-dark-grey w3-xlarge w3-padding-32">Simple AI</li>
            <li class="w3-padding-16">Website with Artificial Intelligence</li>
            <li class="w3-padding-16">15 Pages</li>
            <li class="w3-padding-16">10 Updates</li>
            <li class="w3-padding-16">
            <h2>$ 8 | 30 zł</h2>
            <span class="w3-opacity">Simple AI Website</span>
            </li>
            <li class="w3-light-grey w3-padding-24">
            <button href="mailto:L.L.Zamenhof-Dr.Esperanto@protonmail.com" class="w3-button w3-white w3-padding-large w3-hover-black">Hire Me</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-half w3-margin-bottom">
        <ul class="w3-ul w3-white w3-center w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off">
            <li class="w3-dark-grey w3-xlarge w3-padding-32">Advanced AI</li>
            <li class="w3-padding-16">Website with Artificial Intelligence</li>
            <li class="w3-padding-16">20 Pages</li>
            <li class="w3-padding-16">15 Updates</li>
            <li class="w3-padding-16">
                <h2>$ 10 | 40 zł</h2>
                <span class="w3-opacity">Advanced AI Website</span>
            </li>
            <li class="w3-light-grey w3-padding-24">
                <button href="mailto:L.L.Zamenhof-Dr.Esperanto@protonmail.com" class="w3-button w3-white w3-padding-large w3-hover-black">Hire Me</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```